# Assigning a class attribute to the <head> element in HTML5

Tags: css, html

In HTML 4 and XHTML 1, you can't assign a class to the `<head>` element. However, in XHTML 1.0 you can give it an ID.  In HTML5 it seems you can give it a class.  I am curious, why you would want to?

Comment: I would assume this is for semantic parsing more than anything.

Comment: As others mentioned, there’s no real reason to disallow it. Note that you can [make hidden elements like `<head>` visible using CSS](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-hidden-elements) (although this doesn’t require adding a `class` or `id` attribute to it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`class` is one of what are now called [global attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#global-attributes) (along with global events). They'll have to apply to every single element in the DOM, regardless of its nature.

I believe it's related to the API. The spec defines [every DOM HTML element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#elements-in-the-dom) to inherit from a base interface called `HTMLElement` that defines the aforementioned global attributes and events. Namely:

```idl
interface HTMLElement : Element {

  // ...

  // metadata attributes
           attribute DOMString id;
           attribute DOMString title;
           attribute DOMString lang;
           attribute DOMString dir;
           attribute DOMString className;
  readonly attribute DOMTokenList classList;
  readonly attribute DOMStringMap dataset;
```

With that said, the editor(s) of the spec did make the following note at the end of the list of global attributes/events:

> Note: While these attributes apply to all elements, they are not useful on all elements. For example, only [media elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#media-element) will ever receive a [`volumechange`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#event-media-volumechange) event fired by the user agent.

So I suppose they don't expect you to, but they can neither think of a reason to allow it or **not** to allow it. It's just part of the API (i.e. an [`HTMLHeadElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-head-element) **is** an `HTMLElement` anyway).

Comment: +1 for the very nice technical answer. So yeah, why *would* you want to use a class on `<head>`?

Comment: Interesting, I add a non-existent language hint `<!-- language: lang-idl -->` and the syntax highlighter thinks I'm using C#.

Comment: Was probably intelligently guessing, as without the language declaration.